# Build Referral Program page in swap interface like pancakeswap, pantherswap, coinswap?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, swap, cryptocurrency

I am trying to build the referral program page like https://pantherswap.com/referrals.
I checked the source in github for pantherswap interface. But I can't find any mentions for that section. Could you give me source code for referral program page or any reference article? Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: pantherswap frontend is closed source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is really hard to understand but if you’re looking for the referral section that isn’t on GitHub might I suggest having a look at this gist https://gist.github.com/korrio/f5aa84802dda810b5762aa37a4bd45e4

Scroll down to the section

```
// File: contracts/libs/IPantherReferral.sol
pragma solidity 0.6.12;

interface IPantherReferral {
/**
 * @dev Record referral.
 */
function recordReferral(address user, address referrer) external;

/**
 * @dev Record referral commission.
 */
function recordReferralCommission(address referrer, uint256 commission) external;

/**
 * @dev Get the referrer address that referred the user.
 */
function getReferrer(address user) external view returns (address);
}
```